# Getting a Close Vote Review on a Question you already voted to close

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed

I got this review today: https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/11720311

But I voted to close the question in review before already (not in the review queue).

Is this a bug or intended to happen? If so, why? All you can do is skip at that point.

Comment: Strange, you shouldn't get reviews for questions that you already acted on. You didn't open  bunch of reviews first before you acted on them?

Comment: @rene No. I voted to close this question well before and was chugging at normal speed chaining the CV queue and suddenly got hit with "You already voted to close this question 39 minutes ago"

Comment: I qualify that as a real bug then. No other reports so far?

Comment: @rene The same thing happened to me before with an audit. I got 3 Spam audits in the last while where I had to skip because I couldn't re-flag spam that I was part in deleting.

Comment: @rene I _think_ this happened to me, too. I'll let you know it this happens again.

Comment: Should stuff you've voted to close that you then find in the review queue count as a review?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I agree; showing you a review where *we should reasonably know* that you can't do anything (except perhaps go against your original decision): isn't a good use of your time. This will be fixed next build.